# Python code program using FOR loop not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, coding-style, accumulator

I need to write a program using a FOR loop, to ask the user for 7 deposits.  As the user enters a deposit amount, it needs to update the balance using the accumulation concept.

Also, keep a count of the number of deposits over or equal to 1000 dollars, between 500 and 999 dollars, between 100 and 499 dollars and between 0 and 99.
Output = Display the count in each of the above groups and final balance from all deposits.

Problem: The last input number (deposit) is the only one being register

```
amount1000orover = 0
amount500to999 = 0
amount100to499 = 0
less99 = 0
total = 0

for count in range(7):
 deposit = int(input("Please enter your deposit amount: "))

if deposit >= 1000:
      amount1000orover + 1
      total=total + deposit

if deposit>=500 and deposit<=999:
     amount500to999 = amount500to999 + 1
     total=total + deposit

if deposit>= 100 and deposit<=499:
     amount100to499 = amount100to499 + 1
     total=total + deposit

if deposit>=0 and deposit<=99:
     less99 = less99 + 1
     total=total + deposit

print("You have "+str(amount1000orover)+" deposit over  or equal to 1000 dollars.")
print("You have "+str(amount500to999)+" deposit between 500 and 999 dollars.")
print("You have "+str(amount100to499)+" deposit between 100 and 499 dollars. ")
print("You have "+str(less99)+" deposit below 100 dollars.")
print("Your balance is : "+str(total))
```

Comment: Is this really what your indenting looks like? Should those `if` statements maybe be indented in the loop?

Comment: I guess it is the real indentation, would make sense with why only the last `deposit` is added.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of your code, all of your `if` statements are outside the `for` loop, which means they will only be run for the last user input (`discount`), since this will be the value of `discount` that persists after the loop has finished executing.

You can see this with an example:

```
Please enter your deposit amount: 1
Please enter your deposit amount: 2
Please enter your deposit amount: 3
Please enter your deposit amount: 4
Please enter your deposit amount: 5
Please enter your deposit amount: 6
Please enter your deposit amount: 7
You have 0 deposit over  or equal to 1000 dollars.
You have 0 deposit between 500 and 999 dollars.
You have 0 deposit between 100 and 499 dollars. 
You have 1 deposit below 100 dollars.
Your balance is : 7
```

Instead, you need to indent your `if` statements such that they are inside the `for count in range(7)` loop. You also need to check the contents of your `if` statements, since they do not increment the `amount1000orover` counter as you expect. You may use the `+=` operator to simplify these, i.e.:

```
for count in range(7):                                                          
    deposit = int(input("Please enter your deposit amount: "))                  
                                                                                
    if deposit >= 1000:                                                         
        amount1000orover += 1                                                  
        total=total + deposit                                                   
                                                                                
    if deposit >= 500 and deposit <= 999:                                           
        amount500to999 += 1                                                     
        total += deposit                                                        
                                                                                
    if deposit >= 100 and deposit <= 499:                                          
        amount100to499 += 1                                                     
        total += deposit                                                        
                                                                                
    if deposit >= 0 and deposit <= 99:                                              
        less99 += 1                                                             
        total += deposit
```

Then, the output is as you expect:

```
Please enter your deposit amount: 10001
Please enter your deposit amount: 501
Please enter your deposit amount: 101
Please enter your deposit amount: 11
Please enter your deposit amount: 2
Please enter your deposit amount: 3
Please enter your deposit amount: 4
You have 1 deposit over  or equal to 1000 dollars.
You have 1 deposit between 500 and 999 dollars.
You have 1 deposit between 100 and 499 dollars. 
You have 4 deposit below 100 dollars.
Your balance is : 10623
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your indentation, your if loops should be inside the for loop not outside. It should look something like this

```
amount1000orover = 0
amount500to999 = 0
amount100to499 = 0
less99 = 0
total = 0

for count in range(7):
   deposit = int(input("Please enter your deposit amount: "))

   if deposit >= 1000:
       amount1000orover += 1
       total=total + deposit

   if deposit>=500 and deposit<=999:
       amount500to999 = amount500to999 + 1
       total=total + deposit

   if deposit>= 100 and deposit<=499:
       amount100to499 = amount100to499 + 1
       total=total + deposit

   if deposit>=0 and deposit<=99:
       less99 = less99 + 1
       total=total + deposit

print("You have "+str(amount1000orover)+" deposit over  or equal to 1000 dollars.")
print("You have "+str(amount500to999)+" deposit between 500 and 999 dollars.")
print("You have "+str(amount100to499)+" deposit between 100 and 499 dollars. ")
print("You have "+str(less99)+" deposit below 100 dollars.")
print("Your balance is : "+str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend using elif statements to save a lot of typing. Also, because the money is being categorized into ranges, you are losing specific deposit amounts, though you still have the total. Another way you could solve your problem is like so:

```
_1000_plus = 0
_500_to_999 = 0
_100_to_499 = 0
under_99 = 0
deposits = []  # if you keep a list of deposits then you won't lose that data
for i in range(7):
    deposit = float(input("Please enter your deposit amount: "))  # use float because the user might try to enter cents
    deposits.append(deposit)
    if deposit < 100:
        under_99 += 1
    elif deposit < 500:  # elif is what you want to use. It saves lots of typing
        _100_to_499 += 1
    elif deposit < 1000:
        _500_to_999 += 1
    else:
        _1000_plus += 1

print(f"You have {_1000_plus} deposit over or equal to 1000 dollars.")
print(f"You have {_500_to_999} deposit between 500 and 999 dollars.")
print(f"You have {_100_to_499} deposit between 100 and 499 dollars. ")
print(f"You have {under_99} deposit below 100 dollars.")
print(f"Your balance is : ${sum(deposits):.2f}")  # writes sum of deposits with 2 decimal points
```